# get content inside a div inside a data object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$.get('index.html'), function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

Inside the console log, it prints out everything inside `index.html`. But how do I print out the content only in `<div id="description">Lorem ipsum</div>` inside `data`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.get('index.html'), function(data){
  console.log($("#description",data).text();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery's `load` method to get that specific element from your file and put it into another element:

$( "#result" ).load( "index.html #description" );

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Wowo, didn't know this is possible. Gonna refactor some code using this :-)

Comment: This will work; however, it does not answer the OPs original question. He was specifically asking for how to *print* only #description. This, on the other hand, *retrieves* only #description. It's possible that the OP wanted to get the entire document and only print out specific parts. Using this technique would require multiple HTTP requests if the OP wants to do this many times with different elements.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at .filter() in jQuery's API
http://api.jquery.com/filter/

It will be something like:

```
$(data).filter("#description");
```