# Why am I not getting content from other pages? jQuery $.get function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the content from **page1.html** inside the div **#content**

```
$(function(){
    $.get('page1.html', function(data){
        console.log($("#content",data).html()); <-- console.log says undefined
    });
});
```

**Page1.html**

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
    <h2>Page 1 Content</h2>
</div>
```

I'm not sure why it's not working and console.log appeard **undefined**.

I followed here:
[get content inside a div inside a data object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044124/get-content-inside-a-div-inside-a-data-object#answer-25044162)

Comment: use $("#content").html(data),console.log(data);

Comment: @Bala that is to set the `HTML`.

Comment: @Mritunjay The second parameter of $() would be context,so try made by op is wrong

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do it:

```
var url = 'page1.html';

$(function() {
  $.get(url, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#content').html(data);
  });
});
```

Fiddle using [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org/html): http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/kyu6g3e0/ (tested in Chrome)